# Excel - Matching data across 2 separate workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, comparison

I have 2 separate tabs (tab A and Tab B) on a Workbook that both contain the column called CustomerID - this contains a unique Customer ID number.

On Tab A it is Column B, on tab B it is under column C

I want to compare the 2 tabs to see if the Unique ID appears on both and return a YES/NO answer in Tab B if the same CustomerID does appear on both tabs.

Tried combinations of VLookUp but cannot get it to calculate - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(blah blah)),"No","Yes") should do it.

The VLOOKUP will be B1,B!C:C,1,false.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIF` comes to mind as an easy way to do this.  You can check if `COUNTIF>0` and use `AND` to combine the results for each column.

Formula in `E2` on `Sheet4` (for me).  The range `B2:B20` is for the first sheet.  The range `Sheet5!C2:C17` matches the column on the second sheet.  Adjust those to taste.  `E1` is the `UniqueId` to search for.

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B2:B20,E1)>0, COUNTIF(Sheet5!C2:C17,E1)>0)
```

If you want "Yes/No" instead of `TRUE/FALSE`, wrap the formula above in a `IF(..., "Yes", "No")`

Here is a picture of ranges

[image: picture of ranges]